# Upload Image - Strapi - React Native

Tags: react-native, strapi

I'm new to React Native and Strapi and I want to upload pictures to the API: 
My application allows the user to add a sale ad (Title, Description, Quantity, Number of lots, Price, Photo 1, Photo 2, ...).

I can add a sale ad with text fields but not photos. And I can't find how to do it in Strapi's doc (I use MongoDB). Knowing that Strapi doesn't accept FormData. For the moment I get the picture of the smartphone in "base64" format and send it to the API but it doesn't work.

```
Insert_Into_DataBase = () => {
console.log("insert");
console.log(this.state.image1);

this.setState(
  {
    ActivityIndicator_Loading: true
  },
  () => {
    console.log("fetch");

    fetch("http://192.168.0.102:1337/annonces", {
      method: "POST", 
      headers: {

        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },

      body: JSON.stringify({
        titreAnnonce: this.state.titre, 
        description: this.state.description,
        qte: this.state.disponibilite,
        nbrLots: this.state.lots,
        Image1: this.state.image1
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJsonFromServer => {
        alert(responseJsonFromServer + "L'annonce à bien été postée");
        this.setState({ ActivityIndicator_Loading: false });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        this.setState({ ActivityIndicator_Loading: false });
      });
  }
);
   };
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually to add an upload to an entry (`announces` in your case), you will have to first, create your entry.

Then you will have to use the `/upload` route to upload your file (one by one). There is documentation here about param to set to link the file to the correct entry https://strapi.io/documentation/guides/upload.html#usage

After that if you have an issue about the file format, you can check here https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-upload/controllers/Upload.js#L34 it's where the file format is converted, you will probably to update id to handle `base64` files.

Comment: If I have 4 photos to upload I will have to do :
- POST => Create an ad 
- POST => Upload my photo1
- POST => Upload my photo2
- POST => Upload my photo3
- POST => Upload my photo4
- PUT => Update the fields "photo1", "photo2", "photo3", "photo4" of my ad.

That's a lot of requests. I'll try that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Strapi now allows us to send form data for file upload.
Creating an entity and uploading a file can be done in one post request.
Kindly refer:https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/upload.html